# C# tableLayoutPanel scroll everything except top row

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

I am using winforms with C# and looking at the TableLayoutPanel

Is it possible to have a scroll bar on a large table, but not to have the top row scroll? It would be similar to how the "freeze panes" option works in Excel.

I only want to freeze the top row and nothing else. Also, my table is large enough that I will have a horizontal scroll bar as well. So when I scroll horizontally, I need both the top row and the rest of the rows to move at the same time and the same rate.

Comment: can you not just set the `AutoScroll` property of the TableLayoutPanel to true?

Comment: @ravenx30 That would make the whole table scroll. I want the top row to remain static while everything else scrolls

Comment: TLP has no such feature.  Just put the controls that need to stay put on top of the TLP.  And never, never make the mistake of assuming that TLP is a suitable way of implementing a grid control.  DataGridView already does what you want, lots and lots of grid controls out there.

Comment: @HansPassant thx, didn't know about DGV