# Freeze Headers when vertically scrolling VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls, containers

I have a program that generates textboxes in a `Panel` called "PayeGrid". The panel also contains a `TableLayoutPanel` for displaying Headers for each row of textboxes. See the image below:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqqRe.png)

When running the program, I can scroll horizontally using PayeGrid scroll bars and the Headers also scroll along,as intended, because they are contained within PayeGrid:

[Horizontal Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFRIl.png)

However, when I scroll vertically, the headers also scroll down and disappear from view.

[Vertical Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2DOK.png)

How can I freeze the TableLayoutPanel when scrolling vertically?

Comment: Hi Amin- try out a DatagridView. Unfortunately in TLP there is no _default_ properties for this. You can always create a panel above and manually line up the colum heads etc, but this is very messy and no need since DGV does what you require :) see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380538/c-sharp-tablelayoutpanel-scroll-everything-except-top-row)...

Comment: Just a side possiblity - also have a look at [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) this is a custom control, but if you can get your head around it, it is probably the most powerful tool you can use in lists! I definately advise checking it out, if not now, then at some point in near future :) hth

Comment: Thank you @Chicken, I really didn't want to change the Panel layout and all, but something always told me it would come back at me someday :). ObjectListView looks promising I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

instead of Using Panel and Table Layout Try Using DataGridView ..that may provide freezed header and Scroll its Content Only..

try using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfa1hnpKIzk